# Parsing a text file line by line and extracting string if it matches

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell, parsing, text

We have a text log file similar to below with many users

```
<user>sandip</user>
something
<time>4:38 PM</time>
anything
<elapsed time> 60 mins </elapsed time>
```

We want to extract all users and we did the same simply by

```
Get-Content "C:\LOG\test.txt" | Select-String '(<user>.+</user>)' | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
}
```

We want to parse test file line by line, check if it contains
`user/time/elapsed time`  and [insert it in a dynamic variable if required] make a table of the same

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your Log File follows the same format that i tested with: 
(i.e something like this one:)

[LogFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMYim.png)

This code should work just fine:

*

```
$Lines = get-content .\log.txt
$array = @()
foreach ($line in $lines)
{
if($line -like "<user>*")
{
$obj = New-Object psobject
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UserName" -value $line.Replace("<user>","").Replace("</user>","")
}
if($line -like "<time>*")
{
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Time" -value $line.Replace("<time>","").Replace("</time>","")
}
if($line -like "<elapsed time>*")
{
Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ElapsedTime" -value $line.Replace("<elapsed time>","").Replace("</elapsed time>","")
$array += $obj
}
}
$array | Export-Csv .\test.csv
```

*

Answer (score 0):

A quite compact solution using two regular expressions,

1. with a nonconsuming [positive
   lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to
   split the source file into sections starting with `<user>`
2. inside an if to get -match the current line with an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to insert the found key and value into the current Row of the new table. See this RegEx live on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/V1R4kB/1)

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\22\SO_50988379.ps1

$Table = ForEach ($Section in ((Get-Content .\Test.log -raw) -split '(?=<user>)' -ne '')) {
    $Row = New-Object psobject
    ForEach ($Line in ($Section -split "`r?`n")) {
        if($Line -match "<(user|time|elapsed time)>([^<]+)</\1>"){
            Add-Member -InputObject $Row -MemberType NoteProperty `
                -Name "$($Matches[1])" -value $Matches[2].Trim()
        }
    }
    $Row
}
$Table #| Export-Csv .\test.csv
```

Sample output:

```
> .\SO_50988379.ps1

user   time    elapsed time
----   ----    ------------
sandip 4:38 PM 60 mins
Joshi  8:15 PM 60 mins
```